# A volatility model developed by JP Morgan

Tags: volatility

I am quite confused with this predicting volatility equation:

σ<sup>2</sup><sub>t</sub> = βσ<sup>2</sup><sub>t-1</sub> + (1-β)ε<sup>2</sup><sub>t</sub>

Here is a section from Capital Market Expectations: CFA Level 3 Volume 3 Curriculum (page 27)

https://ibb.co/37Z2M8r

If we have the residual error (Actual Value - Predicted Value) at time t, that means we already have known the actual variance at time t. Then why do we still need to forecast the volatility at time t anyway?

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search, showed that your equation is not correct, as the error term should be taken at lag 1. If that is the case, forecasting has a direct meaning.

Indicatively, check the following:

- Bollen, B., 2015. What should the value of lambda be in the exponentially weighted moving average volatility model?. Applied Economics, 47(8), pp.853-860
- Gabrielsen, A., Kirchner, A., Liu, Z., & Zagaglia, P. (2015). Forecasting value-at-risk with time-varying variance, skewness and kurtosis in an exponential weighted moving average framework. Annals of Financial Economics, 10(01), 1550005

Comment: Could you please add the link, which you managed to search?

Comment: I just added the reference source for you to look it. Please provide the suggestion. Thanks.